# Fiber bundles maps and Product base

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Assume $f:E\rightarrow X\times [a,b]$ is a fiber bundle. Assume $X\times [a,c]$ and $X\times [c,b]$ for some $a<c<b$ are both trivial bundles. Let $h_1:f^{-1}(X\times [a,c])\rightarrow X\times [a,c]\times F$ and $h_1:f^{-1}(X\times [c,b])\rightarrow X\times [c,b]\times F$ be fiber bundles isomorphisms. These maps do not necessarily agree on $f^{-1}(X\times c)$ so we make them agree by 'replacing $h_2$ with the isomorphism $X\times[c,b]\times F\rightarrow X\times [c,b]\times F$' that is given on each slice $X\times x\times F$ by the map $h_1h_2^{-1}:X\times c\times F\rightarrow X\times c\times F$

This is essentially the argument in [https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) (page 21). I don't understand how to explicitly define the isomorphism and why it is even well defined.

Could someone elaborate? without going into things like $Gl(n,K)$ and so on please :)

Answer (score 1):

Write $E_1 = f^{-1}(X\times[a,c])$ and $E_2 = f^{-1}(X \times [c, b])$. By assumption, we have trivializations on $E_1$ and $E_2$; let's call them $h_1 \colon E_1 \to X \times [a,c] \times F$ and $h_2 \colon E_2 \to X \times [c, b] \times F$.

Here's some notation to make everything super explicit:

- Let $\pi_1\colon X \times [c, b] \times F \to X \times F$ be the map defined by $\pi_1(x, t, v) = (x, v)$.
- Let $\pi_2 \colon X \times [c, b] \times F \to [c, b]$ be the map defined by $\pi_1(x, t, v) = t$.
- Define $i_c\colon X\times F \to X\times \{c\} \times F$ by $i_c(x, v)= (x,c,v)$. Note that $i_c\pi_1 = \operatorname{id}_{X\times \{c\} \times F}$.
- Define $\phi \colon X \times F \to X \times F$ by $\phi(x ,v) = \pi_1 h_1 h_2^{-1}(x, c, v)$, so $\phi = \pi_1h_1h_2^{-1}i_c$

We define a map $\alpha \colon X \times [c, b] \times F \to X \times [c, b] \times F$ by putting
$$
    \pi_1(\alpha(x, t, v)) = \phi(x, v)
$$
and
$$
    \pi_2(\alpha(x,t,v)) = t.
$$
These defining properties $\pi_1 \circ \alpha = \phi \circ \pi_1$ and $\pi_2 \circ \alpha = \pi_2$ specify $\alpha$ using the universal property of the product.

Now define $h\colon E \to X \times [a, b] \times F$
by
$$
    h(e) = \begin{cases}
        h_1(e) & e \in E_1 \\
        \alpha(h_2(e)) & e \in E_2 \\
    \end{cases}
$$
This is well-defined because if $e \in E_1 \cap E_2$ then
$$
    \pi_1(\alpha(h_2(e)))
    = \phi\pi_1 h_2 e
    = \pi_1h_1h_2^{-1}i_c \pi_1 h_2 e
    = \pi_1h_1h_2^{-1} h_2e
    = \pi_1(h_1(e))
$$
and
$$
    \pi_2(\alpha(h_2(e))
    = \pi_2(h_2(e)),
$$
so $h_1(e) = \alpha(h_2(e))$.

Comment: Yes: If the intervals $(a,c_1)$ and $(c_2, b)$ overlap, then there is a point $c \in (c_2, c_1)$, and so trivializations on $(a,c_1)$ and $(c_2, b)$ restrict to trivializations on $(a, c]$, and $[c, b)$ respectively, so  then the same argument applies.

Comment: The space $X \times [c, b] \times F$ is a product of $X\times F$ and $[c,b]$ (it's a bit confusing the order it's written in, but that doesn't matter). A point $\xi \in X \times [c, b] \times F$ is completely determined by its projections $\pi_1(\xi) \in X \times F$ and and $\pi_2(\xi) \in [c,b]$. Therefore, to specify a function $\alpha$ into $X \times [c, b] \times F$ it's enough to specify what $\pi_1 \circ \alpha$ and $\pi_2\circ \alpha$ should be.

Comment: I don't think you can make the given trivializations agree necessarily, if that's your question. If $X$ is a single point and $F = \mathbb{R}$ and $E = (-1, 1)\times \mathbb{R}$ and $h_1\colon (-1, 0) \times \mathbb{R} \to (-1, 0) \times \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $h_1(x, y) = (x, y/x)$. There's no way that $h_1$ can be continuously extended to $(-1,1)$.